# How do you bootstrap docker registry in an air-gapped environment?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've been looking at [Considerations for air-gapped registries](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#considerations-for-air-gapped-registries) in the Docker docs.  I get that it would be necessary to populate the registry initially, and then migrate the storage to the air-gapped environment, but there's still a matter of bootstrapping the registry image, itself, since I can't pull it from a public registry (because its air-gapped).  Is it necessary to `save` the image, migrate it however, then `load` it?  Or is there some other mechanism?